# Blazor exception - The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync()

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I my Blazor application I have such exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Dispatcher.AssertAccess()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1.InvokeAsync(TValue arg)
   at MyApplication.Web.Shared.Application.ApplicationBarService.SearchFromUri(NavigationManager navigationManager) in /app/src/MyApplication.Web/Shared/Application/ApplicationBarService.cs:line 132
   at MyApplication.Web.Shared.Application.ApplicationBar.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in /app/src/MyApplication.Web/Shared/Application/ApplicationBar.razor:line 367
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
2020-09-01 10:32:06.818 +00:00 [ERR] Unhandled exception in circuit 'b625BJVxR9Sa5e1W6l6unK0G7RAkkLuM3kbvMggpJV0'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Dispatcher.AssertAccess()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1.InvokeAsync(TValue arg)
   at MyApplication.Web.Shared.Application.ApplicationBarService.SearchFromUri(NavigationManager navigationManager) in /app/src/MyApplication.Web/Shared/Application/ApplicationBarService.cs:line 132
   at MyApplication.Web.Shared.Application.ApplicationBar.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in /app/src/MyApplication.Web/Shared/Application/ApplicationBar.razor:line 367
```

It asks to use InvokeAsync, but I'm already into an "OnAfterRenderAsync"!
So, why do I have such an issue?

In my situation, I have 3 elements

- an ApplicationBarService (global to the app)
- an ApplicationBarComponent.razor
- a page Index.razor

***What I suspect***

The ApplicationBar component is inside the page Index.razor. It means that OnAfterRender is called on ApplicationBar first, then on Index.

So, here is the call stack / order:

1. ApplicationBar.OnAfterRenderAsync ->
2. ApplicationBarService.SearchFromUri -> (CALL DONE WITH AN EventCallback)
3. Index.Search(...)

One problem is that Index.razor is not yet "ready" (no call to OnAfterRender has been done yet). There I cannot do any JS call :-(

Maybe I should do this call once all "parent" are ready, but how ?

***Some code***

It is a simple event

```
public EventCallback<SearchEventArgs> OnSearch;
```

I call it this way:

```
await OnSearch.InvokeAsync(args);
```

And the last code, On Index.razor I have:

```
public async Task Search(SearchArgs args)
{
 base.InvokeAsync( ... );
}
```

The last method is the one called by the event, there I also use base.InvokeAsync to insure I do the call in the right thread ! But even with this I have some issues, I cannot do JS calls because the OnAfterRender has not been called yet !

So, do you have any idea about the problem?

Also, I have to some change, just to be sure to call from the same components.
If you look at the code:

- I call from OnAfterRender, call a "static" class, then go back to the same component. Then this component try to do the last call.
- In the last call I use InvokeAsync and EventCallback (This one should InvokeAsync too)

But even with this, it ask me to call InvokeAsync (But it is done) !!!

[image]

Comment: Post more complete code. The error is caused by StateHasChanged()

Comment: I suspect that your problem is something related in https://blazor-university.com/components/multi-threaded-rendering/invokeasync/?

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, I have added some code (see the last method), there I do a base.InvokeAsync to ensure I'm in the right thread. The problem is that the Index.OnAfterRender has not been called yet, so I cannot do any JS call! I need a way to call one method on ApplicationBar once the Index page is ready (without specific code for this if possible).

Comment: This diagram of the blazor lifecycle method flow is helpful: https://executecommands.com/aspcore-blazor-lifecycle-methods/ could you be calling your code in one of the other lifecycle methods, hence OnAfterRender not being finished yet?

Answer (score 15):

Without seeing all the code its hard to say for sure, but likely you need to surround a `StateHasChanged` like

```
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

Blazor university has a nice [in-depth explanation](https://blazor-university.com/components/multi-threaded-rendering/invokeasync/#:%7E:text=System.InvalidOperationException%3A%20The%20current%20thread%20is%20not%20associated%20with,dispatcher%20%28just%20like%20WPF%20Dispatcher.Invoke%20or%20WinForms%20Control.Invoke%29.).